# conflict errors trying to get npm install to working

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: rss-feed@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"16.13.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (react-dom, react-scripts)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"16.13.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.13.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"16.13.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

Not sure what happened, but everything is in disarray now. I've tried nuking node-modules, cleaning npm cache, forcing the install and using the flag --legacy-peer-deps,
but nothing is working and I'm still getting this error. I could really use a different direction here, and I'm not sure why this started happening in the first place.

My project structure looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Try to read the errors carefully. It says your project uses React version 16.13.1 and @testing-library/react version 13.4.0, and that that the latter uses React ^18.0.0, meaning any version of React that has 18 as the major version. This conflicts with your project's React version, and is what we call a dependency conflict. I'd try to update your project's React version to 18.x.x. This might break other dependencies. In which case, try updating those as well. React 18 is the latest major version of React and came out almost a year ago, so most libraries should support it by now.

Comment: I had tried this before and didn't think it was working. I just nuked the entire project completely, cloned back down from github, and updated the react version as you said (may have required a force install) and everything is back up and running again.